# Complete the column, as far as there is text in the other column with R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy, mutate

I need complete the column, as far as there is text in the other column with

Current dataframe

```
first_column <- c("eeer","","","sdfdfdsf", "sdfsdfdsf","faffa", "we", "", "", "", "", "", "eeee", "", "wqwq", "", "ttetxg", "", "sf", "sf","f", "dfsdf", "sqdweg", "sfsfdsdvghhh", "")
second_column <- c("","", "","", "", "", "", "renato paulo", "", "", "", "", "", "carlos gomes", "", "", "", "vitor", "","","","","","", "Cassia rabelo")
current_dataframe <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)
```

desired output

```
first_column <- c("eeer","","","sdfdfdsf", "sdfsdfdsf","faffa", "we", "", "", "", "", "", "eeee", "", "wqwq", "", "ttetxg", "", "sf", "sf","f", "dfsdf", "sqdweg", "sfsfdsdvghhh", "")
second_column <- c("","", "","renato paulo", "renato paulo", "renato paulo", "renato paulo", "", "", "", "", "", "carlos gomes", "", "", "", "vitor", "", "Cassia rabelo","Cassia rabelo","Cassia rabelo","Cassia rabelo","Cassia rabelo","Cassia rabelo", "")
desired_output <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)
```

I tried using the fill downup function, it didn't work as I needed. can anybody help me?

Comment: The second column is shifted down by one row in *Current dataframe*. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

An approach that includes shifting *second_column* up by one.

```
library(dplyr) # dplyr > 1.1.0 for *consecutive_id()*

data.frame(first_column = current_dataframe$first_column, 
           second_column = c(
             current_dataframe$second_column[2:nrow(current_dataframe)], "")) %>% 
  group_by(grp = consecutive_id(first_column != "")) %>% 
  mutate(second_column = last(second_column)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  data.frame()
   first_column second_column
1          eeer              
2                            
3                            
4      sdfdfdsf  renato paulo
5     sdfsdfdsf  renato paulo
6         faffa  renato paulo
7            we  renato paulo
8                            
9                            
10                           
11                           
12                           
13         eeee  carlos gomes
14                           
15         wqwq              
16                           
17       ttetxg         vitor
18                           
19           sf Cassia rabelo
20           sf Cassia rabelo
21            f Cassia rabelo
22        dfsdf Cassia rabelo
23       sqdweg Cassia rabelo
24 sfsfdsdvghhh Cassia rabelo
25
```

Comment: Error in `add_computed_columns()`:
! Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` column `grp`.
i `grp = consecutive_id(first_column != "")`.
x could not find function "consecutive_id"
Caused by error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` column `grp`.
i `grp = consecutive_id(first_column != "")`.
x could not find function "consecutive_id"
Caused by error in `consecutive_id()`:
! could not find function "consecutive_id"

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/consecutive_id.html

Comment: the columns have the same number of rows

Comment: `consecutive_id` is available in dplyr > 1.1.0. If you can't update add `library(data.table)` and use `... group_by(grp = rleid(first_column != "")) ...`